# How to pass value one component to another component after getting response from an API in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on an issue with an API. After coming the response from an API, I want to pass the value to the child component. There I will execute method and get response, and show it on the screen.

Code:

```js
    ngOnInit() {
            const userId = '2';
            this.apiService.collectIds(userId)
            .subscribe(ids => {
                this.ids = ids
            }, error => {
                console.log('error', error);
            });
        }
```

Child component:

```html
    <app-chart [ids]="ids"></app-chart>
```

Comment: You can create dynamic component when the response is come, then pass variables to the component. Whenever you want, you can destroy the component, access all public variables, interact with the component.

Comment: Please show the whole code in your parent and child components. Assuming that you declared `@Input` like @Dino mentioned, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way for communicating between parent-child components is using the [@Input](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) and [@Output](https://angular.io/api/core/Output) decorators.

For your specific case you have to use [@Input](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) decorator

In your child component app-chart you would declare it like this:

```
@Input() ids: number; // Or which ever the type you have
```

In your example you are getting the value from a service. Angular will automatically take care of updating the @Input element in your child component when ever it changes in a parent one. If you don't have to execute any methods on input's change (in child component) you don't have to do anything else (Like subscription, async pipe, etc.).

Comment: yeah , after getting response from an api, i want to execute a method in child component. how to do it please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

did u try putting async in the view ?

```
<app-chart [ids]="ids | async"></app-chart>
```

more about async usage https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: This only works if `ids` is of type `Observable<T>`

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
ngOnInit() {
       const userId = '2';
       this.collectIds$ =  this.apiService.collectIds(userId);
}
```

in html:

```
<app-chart [ids]="(collectIds$|async)?.ids"></app-chart>
```